# Building a simple to-do list app with SwiftUI - date formatting

Tags: core-data, swiftui, datepicker, swiftui-list, dateformatter

I’m playing about with SwiftUI for the first time with a simple to do style app. It has 2 views, one a list view, and the other an Add To Do view, which saves info into core data. In core data I have an entity called ToDo with 2 attributes - title (String) and completion (Date).

In the list view I would like to show the entry - the title and completion date on the same line. I thought I would use string interpolation to do this but run into this error:

> Cannot convert value of type 'String' to expected argument type 'Date’.

The code I am using is this:

`Text ("\(listedToDo.title!) needs completing by \(listedToDo.completion!)”)`

I’ve not really worked with DatePickers and DateFormatters before but it may be how I’m saving the date into core data on the Add Item View?

On that file I added the following variable to your code:
`@state var toDoCompletion = Date()`

I added this DatePicker to the view: 
`DatePicker(“Completion date:", selection: $toDoCompletion, displayedComponents: .date)`

And the save code:
`let newToDoCompletion = ToDo(context: viewContext)`
`newToDoCompletion.completion = toDoCompletion`

How can I finish this last bit on the list view?

Comment: Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and see: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example (MRE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I understand your purpose but according to the error message and the code you post, it's not related. Could you add full codes?

Comment: Thanks @QuangHà I've got it sorted now. I was saving into multiple records in core data rather than the one.